# Active Model Serializers : undefined method `url_for' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I'm using `active_model_serializers` gem in my application to send high level json response. It does actually works fine but since I've install that gem, after few minutes of use, the application crash, showing the error above.

Not sure if my code is related to it but somehow, I needed to send back some partial as well. Since it didn't seems to be supported by the gem, I did a work around :

```
class AppSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  def render_partial_to_json(options = {})
    partial = options[:partial] || nil
    locals  = options[:locals] || nil

    context = Rails.configuration.paths['app/views']
    view    = ActionView::Base.new(context)

    view.class.class_eval do
      include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
      include ApplicationHelper
    end

    view.render(
      partial: partial,
      locals: locals
    )
  end
end
```

Then, in my serializer, I can do :

```
class ActivitySerializer < AppSerializer

  attributes :id, :kind, :data, :created_at, :html

  has_many :comments
  has_one :user

  def id
    ScatterSwap.hash(object.id)
  end

  def html
    render_partial_to_json(
      partial: 'activities/post',
      locals: { activity: object }
    )
  end
end
```

This code works fine, and I'm getting my partial as JSON attributes.
The weird thing is that the error appears progressively on any page. The only way to remove it is by restarting the server. But again, after few minutes of use, the problem comes back.

Here is a part of the log :

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 65ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `url_for' for nil:NilClass:
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:155:in `url_for'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/routing_url_for.rb:83:in `url_for'
turbolinks (2.2.1) lib/turbolinks/xhr_url_for.rb:12:in `url_for_with_xhr_referer'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:234:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:178:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:274:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
app/views/activities/_post.html.haml:2:in `_app_views_activities__post_html_haml__1000109198282705156_2214339020'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:306:in `render_partial'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:279:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:278:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
haml (4.1.0.beta.1) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:10:in `block in render_with_haml'
haml (4.1.0.beta.1) lib/haml/helpers.rb:89:in `non_haml'
```

Any of you already face something similar?

**EDIT :**
As requested, here is the code of my view :

```
%article#comment-id-1.comment-item.m-t


= link_to profile_url(activity.user), class: "pull-left thumb-sm avatar" do
  = display_picture_for activity.user, resizing_by: "36x36"
  %span.arrow.left
  %section.comment-body.panel.panel-default
    %header.panel-heading.bg-white
      = link_to profile_url(activity.user) do
        = activity.user.fullname
      %span.text-muted.m-l-sm.pull-right
        %i.fa.fa-clock-o
        = time_ago_in_words activity.created_at
    .panel-body
      %div
        = activity.data[:message]
      .comment-action.m-t-sm
        %a.btn.btn-default.btn-xs.active{"data-toggle" => "class", href: "#"}
          %i.fa.fa-star-o.text-muted.text
          %i.fa.fa-star.text-danger.text-active
          Like
        %a.btn.btn-default.btn-xs{href: "#comment-form"}
          %i.fa.fa-mail-reply.text-muted
          Reply
```

**EDIT 2 :**

After digging a bit more, I found out that this code :

```
class AppSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  def render_partial_to_json(options = {})
    partial = options[:partial] || nil
    locals  = options[:locals] || nil

    context = Rails.configuration.paths['app/views']
    view    = ActionView::Base.new(context)

    view.class.class_eval do
      include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
      include ApplicationHelper
    end

    view.render(
      partial: partial,
      locals: locals
    )
  end
end
```

when calling is overriding Rails helpers and loading libraries, which cause the entire system to be unworking. However, how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show what is happening in: `app/views/activities/_post.html.haml`

Comment: I don't think the problem comes from the view though since it happening on all pages progressively. Also, when request (using Ajax) this partial through `ActiveModel::Serializer`, I got it and inject it  to the DOM using Angular and it's working.

Comment: I have experienced the same problem when I was using 
    view.class.class_eval do
      include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
      include ApplicationHelper
    end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally found a work around. The problem really came from my **edit 2** point in the above post.

To fix it, since I was already using the `rails_config` gem (https://github.com/railsjedi/rails_config) in my app, I've used it in order to be able to render my partials directly from my serializer without breaking the Rails magic autoloading.

First, I'm setting up the context as a config (Settings) :

```
# application_controller
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_context_for_serializer

  def set_context_for_serializer
    Settings.context = self
  end
end
```

Then, within my serializer, all I need to do is :

```
class ApplicationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  def render_partial_to_json(options = {})
    partial = options[:partial] || nil
    locals  = options[:locals] || nil

    Settings.context.render_to_string(
      partial: partial,
      layout: false,
      formats: :html,
      locals: locals
    )
  end
end

class ActivitySerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id, :kind, :data, :created_at, :html

  def html
    render_partial_to_json(
      partial: 'activities/post',
      locals: { activity: object }
    )
  end
end
```

And that's it, now it works perfectly. If you guys have some other way (more Rails like) to do it, I'll be curious to know about it.

Thanks